# How to set title Edit and Done for Button from UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I have a problem,Top button does not change own name but it works

```
- (IBAction)switchEdit:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    sender.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Edit", @"Done", nil];
    if (sender.style == UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit){
        sender.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        self.tableView.editing = NO;
            }else{
        sender.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        self.tableView.editing = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `UIViewController`'s [`editButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem) property, since it seems to do automatically what you need:

> Returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state
>   between Edit and Done.

If you want to keep your approach, you can declare these two buttons as properties and set them up in `viewDidLoad` for example, like that:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *editBarButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButtonItem;

@end
```

and then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.editBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editSelectorName)];
    self.doneBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneSelectorName)];
}
```

and then in your code just do:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editBarButtonItem
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneBarButtonItem
```